# Hide Div scrollbar for a particular js/jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

I did hide the scrollbar on a div that has overflow:scroll using jquery the way.

```
$('body').css('overflow','hidden');
```

It is working fine.

The problem is, this is hiding scroll bar on all the jsp's in my appliations.

But I just want to hide scroll bar on my js/jsp page alone.

Is there any way to hide only for single js/jsp, eventhough it is common div?

Can anyone help me in this issue?

Comment: set body width to 100%!important

Comment: well than include the script only on that js/jsp page?

Comment: @Krab I did the same, but the problem is this js code is overriding by default in all jsp's.. and also i cant go now and change all the other jsp's now...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide scrollbars for some div's and add a class for those div's and use the following code.(ex: class="scrollhide")

```
$('div.scrollhide').css('overflow','hidden');
```

Comment: I agree with you , but the issue is that div is common for all the jsp's in my application

Comment: @sandy You want to Hide Div scrollbar for a particular js/jsp, in your jsp create a global variable (var isScrollHide=true), if it is true then execute above code.